# Fit curve and/or linear approximation to data points in Maxima

Tags: curve-fitting, maxima, wxmaxima

I have a set of data points that lie on a simple curve and I'd like to find a tangent to that curve at a specific point. I don't have an expression for the curve. Can Maxima calculate either the tangent line or give me an expression for a good curve that fits my data points? It's only 20 data points if that makes any difference.

Comment: I found out the answer is yes - using the interpol package: https://maths.cnam.fr/Membres/wilk/MathMax/help/Maxima/maxima_57.html. You can just do laplace(my_points) for instance and get a polynomial expression matched to those points.

Comment: John, I'm glad to hear you found something useful. Bear in mind the link shows documentation for an out of date version of Maxima; you can always find the latest version at: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/documentation.html You can also get advice from the maxima-discuss mailing list; see: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss Finally, I think you meant `lagrange` instead of `laplace` in your comment above.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks for the info. Yes I meant lagrange but it looks like it's too late to edit the comment now.